# Xamarin Forms HybridWebview Always Opens in Browser

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-webview

I've implemented a HybridWebView as described here:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/

For now, I have the url hardcoded in the renderer, like this:

```
Control.LoadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

The result is the url opens, but always in a new browser, not embedded in my ContentPage as I would expect.

Is there a Settings property on the Android.Webkit.WebView I can use to determine how it displays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The result is the url opens, but always in a new browser, not embedded in my ContentPage as I would expect.

For android platform, it uses `Android.Webkit.WebView` as native control as you can see it from code:

```
if (Control == null) {
    var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView (Forms.Context);
    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    SetNativeControl (webView);
}
```

Then for `Android.Webkit.WebView`, if you don't enable the activity to handle the intent to view a web page, it is a simple web page viewer, not quite a browser yet because as soon as you click a link, the default Android Browser handles it. To enable it, this code can go anywhere following the initialization of `WebView`: `webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())`. So you may add this code for example:

```
if (Control == null) {
    var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView (Forms.Context);
    webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    SetNativeControl (webView);
}
```

Usually we can also subclass `WebViewClient` and override [ShouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebViewClient.ShouldOverrideUrlLoading/p/Android.Webkit.WebView/System.String/), if it returns true, means that method has handled the URL and the event should not propagate.